# MySQL Cronjob won't start via cronjob

Tags: bash, scripts, mysql, cron

after hours of trying and searching i don't find the error.

I have a cronjob (on root user)

```
30 2 * * * /cronjobs/mysql/mysql_cleanup_db.sh >> /cronjobs/mysql/cleanup.log
```

this (`mysql_cleanup_db.sh`) starts a shell script (the cnf file only includes the user and password)

```
#!/bin/bash
CONF=/cronjobs/mysql/conf/minecraft.cnf
/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-extra-file=$CONF "minecraft" < "/cronjobs/mysql/lbWorld.sql"
```

and this (`lbWorld.sql`) should execute the sql commands

```
DELETE FROM minecraft.`lb-world` WHERE `playerid` = 11;
```

I have no idea what was wrong. No error occurs and no log will be written.

Any ideas?

If i start the shell via commandline manually it will work. The difference in the shell file is this:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=$CONF minecraft < lbWorld.sql
```

Comment: Since you don't appear to be redirecting errors anywhere, how do you know that *"no error occurs"*? Have you tried adding `2>&1` to the end of the command?

Comment: I think this is correct and the output will be written in the `test.log` file - true?
`/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-extra-file=$CONF "minecraft" < "/cronjobs/mysql/lbWorld.sql" >> "/cronjobs/mysql/test.log" 2>&1`
I don't receive an output in this file.

Comment: If you add `2>&1` after the cron command itself (in the crontab) then you will also see any errors associated with running the shell script - first step to solving this is finding out whether the script fails to run, or the mysql command inside the script fails to run.

Comment: I had also added this to crontab, but also no output received in the file `cleanup.log`. 
Crontab line: 
`03 21 * * * /cronjobs/mysql/mysql_cleanup_db.sh >> /cronjobs/mysql/cleanup.log 2>&1`

Comment: If you delete the log file is it recreated? is `/cronjobs/mysql/mysql_cleanup_db.sh` actually executable (i.e. can you run `/cronjobs/mysql/mysql_cleanup_db.sh` directly in a terminal)?

Comment: Yes, if i delete the log files they will be recreated after crontab runs. Yes, it will work (with a little modification) - see my main post (last two lines of it). But over the crontab this solution also not work.

Comment: Additional info: i added `/usr/bin/mysqldump` instead of `/usr/bin/mysql` and the dump output was created in the `cleanup.log`

Comment: no further ideas whats wrong or what i can test?

Comment: Update: The deletion work now correctly (nothing is changed - only system updates are installed). So it is solved.